# JSON parsing in Java not finding items

Tags: java, json

I have the following JSON text to parse in Java:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "key": "D033222DF44E5308482578EB0017588A",
            "Date": "Aug 13 2011",
            "Time": "04:54:46 PM",
            "Company": "CHINA ESSENCE GROUP LTD.",
            "AnnTitle": "FIRST QUARTER RESULTS * FINANCIAL STATEMENT AND RELATED ANNOUNCEMENT",
            "Siblings": "18",
            "SNo": 18
        },
        {
            "key": "C9906046C7F0E232482578EB0030C437",
            "Date": "Aug 13 2011",
            "Time": "04:52:12 PM",
            "Company": "DESIGjsonN STUDIO FURNITURE MFRLTD",
            "AnnTitle": "NOTICE OF BOOK CLOSURE DATE FOR DIVIDEND",
            "Siblings": "18",
            "SNo": 17
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is my JSONParser class:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSONParser {

private String input = null;

public JSONParser() {
}

public JSONParser(String input) {
    setInput(input);
}

public JSONArray parse() throws JSONException {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    return obj.getJSONArray("items");
}

/**
 * @return the input
 */
public String getInput() {
    return input;
}

/**
 * @param input the input to set
 */
public void setInput(String input) {
    this.input = input;
}
}
```

My main() method class contains these codes to execute the parser to parse the "jsonStr" object:

```
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(jsonStr);
        JSONArray array = parser.parse();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            Object obj = array.get(i);
            System.out.println(">> " + obj.toString() + "\n");
        }
```

My output shows:

```
SEVERE: null
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["items"] not found.
```

I am using the json.org provided Java codes for JSON.

How should I parse the above string ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not actually passed the input string to the JSON parsing library. The `JSONParser#parse()` method needs to (somehow) use `this.input`. Try this:

```
public JSONArray parse() throws JSONException
{
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(this.input);
    return obj.getJSONArray("items");
}
```

---

That said, [`org.json.JSONObject`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java) is an ancient implementation. I would **strongly** encourage you to use a more modern JSON library, such as one of the following:

- [JSON.simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)
- [Google GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)
- [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)